# Meaning of "saga" in a Queens of Stone Age song

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

I am having trouble to understand the meaning of the word "saga" in the following excerpt of a Queens of Stone Age [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/millionaire-lyrics-queens-of-the-stone-age.html):

> How we feeling out there? How's your drive time commute?
>       I need a saga, what's the saga?
>       It's songs for the deaf, you can't even hear it
>
> ("You Think I Ain't Worth A Dollar, But I Feel Like A Millionaire"
>        - written by Josh Homme and Mario Lalli)

These are actually the words of a fictional radio host introducing the song, and "songs for the deaf" is the name of the album.

"Saga", in that context, doesn't seem to match any of the following meanings in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/saga):

> 1a. A prose narrative usually written in Iceland between 1120 and 1400, 
>             dealing with the families that first settled Iceland and their 
>             descendants, with the histories of the kings of Norway, and with the 
>             myths and legends of early Germanic gods and heroes.
>
> 1b. A modern prose narrative that resembles a saga.
>
> 2. A long detailed report: recounted the saga of their family problems.

Neither it matches the definitions in [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SAGA&utm_source=search-action), supposing it is a slang.

I can only interpret that the radio host wants to listen to something epic.

Comment: Your guess is as good as anyone else's.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-standard word usage in lyrics, only relevant in this context.

Comment: I beg to disagree. In Help Center > Asking, they say you can ask "Word choice and usage" and "Practical problems you encounter while learning English".

Comment: I think @user3169 is saying that, because this is a poetic and non-standard usage of _saga_, we're unlikely to find a definitive answer. (Of course, there's no way for you to know that before  you ask the question.)

Comment: I think that this is primarily opinion based. I can't think of any objective way to arrive at a meaning based on the context.

Comment: I can't tell what it means. I tried googling to see if **saga** has acquired some slang meaning, but I didn't find anything. At best, I think it is just extremely unclear.

Comment: Wait a minute, I found it: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Music/QueensOfTheStoneAge

Comment: The only thing I see in the link is "Album Title Drop: Sometimes, albums aren't named for one of the songs on them — they're named for one of the lyrics within these songs". It is just that the name of the album comes from that excerpt.

Comment: @fcpenha: It's artistic usage, so there are any number of possible interpretations, but I think your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @ColleenV I think it calls for LitCrit: not subjective opinion but objective opinion.

Comment: @fcpenha I mean the part by "Album Title Drop" where it explains that the "saga" is _Songs for the Deaf,_ a hidden track containing low frequencies that deaf people may be able to detect. StoneyB's answer explains more.

Comment: I really don't understand why it has been marked as off-topic. If it is really, whoever marked should seriously think about removing the tag "meaning-in-context" from the forum. I am serious about that.

Comment: @fcpenha - Meaning-in-context questions are much easier to answer when they are not part of a poem or song lyric.

Comment: @J.R. of course I agree with you. But the discussion should not be about the level of difficulty. If it was easy, I could have solved myself.

Comment: @fcpenha - Most of this discussion is not about "level of difficulty;" it's about whether it's possible for anyone other than the author to understand the meaning. Traditionally, questions about song lyrics are often closed, both on ELU and on ELL, because lyrics are often abstract, obtuse, unclear, and [subject to debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Betty#Meaning_and_origin). There are [entire websites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SongMeanings) devoted to such debate, but SE isn't one of them. If a song lyric confuses a native speaker, don't be surprised to see close votes.

Comment: As another example, consider [_American Pie_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_(song)). When asked what the song meant, McLean jokingly replied, "It means I don't ever have to work again if I don't want to." He later said, "You will find many interpretations of my lyrics but none of them by me .. Sorry to leave you all on your own like this but long ago I realized that songwriters should make their statements and move on, maintaining a dignified silence." Interesting quote on the matter – and it's why I'd probably vote to close a question asking us to interpret _American Pie_ :^)

Comment: One last quote for you – one I don't agree with, but I found this on a website: "It seems every one of the Beatle’s lyrics are about drugs, communism, illicit acts and psychadelic drug-enabled sounds that confuse the mind." My answer to that is, "Sure, if you look hard enough, and bend the words, you can probably get their lyrics to allude to just about anything you want." Or, as McCartney himself once said, "Everything has a double meaning if you look for it long enough."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, a little context helps. This is not actually the lyric of the opening track but its introduction: we're listening to voices from morning drivetime radio.

> **Voice 1**: *K L O N, Los Angeles, clone radio. We play the songs that sound more like everyone else than anyone else. Clone.*
>
> **Voice 2**: Hey alright, it's Kip Casper clone radio, L.A.'s infinite repeat. How we feeling out there? How's your drive time commute? I need a *saga*, what's the *saga*? ...
> It's Songs for the Deaf, you can't even hear it.

It is after that that the song starts, very loud and heavy:

> Dead blow with the life from the low
> I’ll be massive conquistador
> Give me sword, show me the door
> Metal heavy, shocked at the core
> Gimme toro, gimme some more
> Gimme toro, gimme some more
> Pressurize, neutralize
> Deep fried, gimme some more
> Space flunky, four on the floor
> Fortified with the liquor store
> This one's down, gimme some more
> Gimme toro, gimme some more ... (3x)

There's more lyric, but it's mostly that last line, “Gimme toro, gimme some more”, repeated over and over.

QOTSA proclaims the superiority of its own raucous, violent style (“Metal heavy, shocked at the core”) to the contemptible (“toro” = bullshit), uninspired four-beat music drunken yuppies dance to in night clubs (“Space flunky, four on the floor, Fortified with the liquor store”).

The opening sequence expresses the band’s contempt for “clone” radio stations and their pretentious DJs who petulantly demand “saga”—music that is heroic, bigger than life—but are in fact incapable of recognizing real saga, truly musical music. This is a “Song for the Deaf”: the band in effect tells the DJ “You want saga? We’ll give you saga”—QOTSA come as “conquistadors” to wield the heavy metal “sword” against the DJ and his banal “songs that sound more like everyone else than anyone else”.

[This reading has been confirmed and enhanced by my son, a rock drummer (among other things) who is a particular fan of the drummer on this album, Dave Grohl.]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I hadn't realized that the upcoming lyrics were that epic. Now, for the context of clone radios in the USA, there was no way that I would know that. Thank you again.

Comment: @fcpenha Well, it's epic in a saga sort of way. Metal is to pop more or less as the Vikings were to 9th-century monasteries.