# What does "right" mean in "gonna tell you right"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Your butt is mine
>   Gonna tell you **right**
>   Just show your face
>   In broad daylight
>   I'm telling you
>   On how I feel
>   Gonna hurt your mind
>   Don't shoot to kill
>   Come on

Source: [Michael Jackson -- Bad (MetroLyrics)](http://www.metrolyrics.com/bad-lyrics-michael-jackson.html)

Does it mean *right away*? Or maybe it has been used for emphasis? Is this a slang usage?

Comment: *right* here is not slang; it is obviously not combined with 'away.' So the word has its usual meaning as an adverb. I suggest you check a good dictionary for the meaning of *right* as an adverb. Here is [a good start](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/right).

Comment: @CarSmack I always use a dictionary before consulting this site. However, commonly used words such as _right_ have so many meanings that I sometimes don't know which one is "right" in a given context. :P And this is one of these cases.

Comment: Even in context, can be read two ways - 'I'm gonna tell you, with emphasis, OK?' or 'I'm going to tell you the correct information'. Both are colloquial, both require context. In that kind of 'confrontational' context of the lyric, it's almost impossible without voice-tone to distinguish, which would probably disappear in the meter of the song.

Comment: @user12257 - If you "always consult a dictionary first," why not at least share where you looked and what you found? That's how [Yoichi](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465) would do it. In any case, I think "Gonna tell you right" is similar to "Gonna set you straight", but it's hard to say for sure in a song. When dealing with lyrics, some words get picked because they rhyme, and [true meanings are notoriously hard to interpret](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41488/meaning-of-saga-in-a-queens-of-stone-age-song#comment78001_41488).

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is slang, and has nothing to do with when he will say something, but how he's going to say it. If you listen to the song "Bad," and watch the video you will see it's all confrontation. The singer, Michael Jackson, is saying he's going to speak the truth and he's going to say it without regard to consequences or the listener's feelings.